# GameKit Turn-Based AND Real Time Match

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

I'm working on a simple Game Center Multiplayer game that has two players; the game is set up like a timed chess match, where each player takes a turn, but only has x amount of seconds to act. I think that the timer is necessary to keep players engaged and to avoid long periods of inactivity that can occur with Turn-Based. I've looked at the Apple Docs for both Turn-Based and Real-Time matches, but still can't find a solution to my problem.

Simply, this game has three requirements:

- Needs Game Center/GameKit Implementation
- Players must take turns
- Players must be held to a time limit

What approach is best for this scenario? Real-Time or Turn-Based? Could they be used simultaneously?

I appreciate your help!

P.S. I will probably have a couple of follow-up questions regarding proper implementation.

Comment: In a GameKit turn-based game you control when a "move" is made (you write the code after all).  Why don't you just "skip" a person's turn if they don't move within the required time interval? This seems like turn-based would be the best option for you.

Comment: @RoboticCat Exactly. However--and this may be incorrect, I have limited experience with this framework--it seems that when a user starts a new turn based game, the opponent does not necessarily have to be present, unlike real-time matchmaking where both players must be present to begin. Is there a method via turn-based matchmaking delegate to do this? That is, delay the beginning of the game until auto-match, etc. has joined two players together? I only ask because, while your suggestion is great, the first one or two turns might have a problem with intermittent player activity.

Comment: I'm not a GameKit expert either but if the docs don't indicate there is an API for this I would make the first move of each player a "setup" move (maybe indicate their readiness in the app) and then go straight into the game once both have indicated their readiness.

Comment: @RoboticCat I like it! Thanks!